# Lua how to require a file from remote http

Tags: lua

I want to access a file over http then have the functions available as if I "require" a local file.

```
local file_url = "http://127.0.0.1:800/myfile.lua"

local http = require("socket.http")
local remote = http.request(file_url)
```

```
require "remote"
```

How do I do it

Comment: loadstring or dofile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual act of [loading packages in `require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require) is performed by a [series of functions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) stored in the `package.searchers` table (in Lua 5.2+ parlance. 5.1 uses `package.loaders`, but it's the same idea). All you need to do is add a searcher function that can handle "packages" whose names are URLs:

```
local http = require("socket.http")

local function http_loader(module_uri)

    --I don't know what this function does, so I assume it returns the actual text of the file.
    --If not, feel free to insert whatever the `socket` module needs to retrieve the text at the URI.
    local module_text = http.request(module_uri) 

    --Always do error checking.
    if --[[did the request succeed?]] then
        return loadstring(module_text)
    else
        return "could not find HTTP module name " .. module_uri
    end
end

table.insert(package.searchers, http_loader)
```

With this, you ought to be able to execute `require "http://127.0.0.1:800/myfile.lua"` directly.

If instead you have some specific modules across the network which you want to pre-load, you can [use the `packages.preload` table](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.preload). For example, if you want to preload a Lua file at `http://127.0.0.1:800/myfile.lua` using the module name "remote", you can do this:

```
local http = require("socket.http")

local function http_preload(module_uri, module_name)
    local module_text = http.request(module_uri) --Again, assuming this is the text.

    --Always do error checking.
    if --[[did the request succeed?]] then
        package.preload[module_name] = loadstring(module_text)
        return true
    else
        return nil, "could not find HTTP module name " .. module_uri
    end
end

assert(http_preload("http://127.0.0.1:800/myfile.lua", "remote"))

require "remote" --Includes the loaded file.
```

Now, neither of these methods will magically allow any modules from `myfile.lua` to access networked resources. If you use the first method, and `myfile.lua` requires some resources local to itself (ie: on the server), then it will have to access them via HTTP just as if it were on the client (because that's where it got loaded from).

If you use the second method, you will *have to* `http_preload` the modules in an order so that no module attempts to load a resource that has not yet been preloaded.